# Defining observation space and reward for traffic signal phase optimization for reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, sumo

I am trying to use Reinforcement Learning for traffic signal phase optimization for improving traffic flow at intersections.

I am aware that in practice we won't be able to get the information about all the vehicles in each of the lanes.
If we use a camera for getting information about the queue length then we can get accurate data only upto, say 200 meters.

Should I take this into consideration while defining my observation space or can I directly use the data from sumo?

Furthermore, what should be the ideal observation space for such a task?

`sumo_rl` allows to use various metrics for reward calucation such as pressure metric, queue length metric, etc. What will be a good choice of rewards for my use case or what factors should I consider while defining my reward?

I have tried getting metrics from the e2 detector's output file such as throughput, lane delay and queue length. For the agent however, I might not be able to use them (as traci/sumo wrappers offer better implementations?) So how do I use traci for getting this modified information?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you should try to match your observation space as close to the real world as possible. SUMO can also filter the data directly (for instance with an E3 detector).
2. If you want to maximize flow than the reward should also include the flow metric (throughput). It's quite easy to get it via traci (as you already noticed) but I cannot tell how it integrates with your framework since you did not give details about it.

Comment: Can you suggest some metrics for the observation space? I will be looking for papers simultaneously but some experience always helps. Some things that I have seen so far:

1. Current green signal phase

2. Queue length for each lane

3. Mean delay for each lane (This one might not be possible to calculate in the real world using cameras)

Comment: No, sorry I do not have a lot of experience with it myself